# Advanced Dual Wielding

Tags: diablo-ii

I am playing a frenzy Barb and trying to figure out which weapon to put into my mainhand. First weapon is slow but hits hard, second is fast but hits not as hard as the first one.

This [ias calculator](https://diablo3.ingame.de/diablo-2/calculatoren/angriffsgeschwindigkeit/?lang=en) shows a higher attack speed when I put the faster weapon into the mainhand. Does that mean that you always put the faster weapon into the mainhand?

Comment: They only say that it makes no difference which weapon you hold in your mainhand, which is not true

Comment: It doesn't say it makes no difference. It says the only difference is you start attacking with your right hand weapon, but overall it doesn't affect anything else (doesn't really affect skills for example).

Comment: But according to the ias calculator it does affect attack speed

Comment: The calculator could be wrong?